# Multiple Pen's Parade Graphs on the same Plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm doing stochastic dominance analysis with diferent income distributions using Pen's Parade. I can plot a single Pen's Parade using `Pen` function from `ineq` package, but I need a visual comparison and I want multiple lines in the same image. I don't know how extract values from the function, so I can't do this.

I have the following reproducible example:

```
set.seed(123) 
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0.2) 
library(ineq) 
Pen(x) 
Pen(y)
```

I obtain the following plots:

I want obtain sometime as the following:

Comment: `Pen(x);
par(new=TRUE);
Pen(y)`

Comment: Just a comment on how to get what data actually `Pen` plots. You can create the data used by the function by looking into the function body: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `add = TRUE`:

```
set.seed(123) 
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0.2) 
library(ineq) 
Pen(x); Pen(y, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

From `help("Pen")`:

> add      logical. Should the plot be added to an existing plot?

While the solution mentioned by [M-M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6461462/m-m) in the comments is a more general solution, in this specific case it produces a busy Y axis:

```
Pen(x)
par(new = TRUE) 
Pen(y)
```

[image]

I would generalize the advice for plotting functions in this way:

1. Check the plotting function's help file. If it has an `add` argument, use that.
2. Otherwise, use the `par(new = TRUE)` technique

### Update

As M-M helpfully mentions in the comments, their more general solution will not produce a busy Y axis if you manually suppress the Y axis on the second plot:

```
Pen(x)
par(new = TRUE) 
Pen(y, yaxt = "n")
```

[image]

Comment: Using `par(new=T)` almost always requires setting one of the plot's axis to `NULL`. That's just the how it is. But anyhow, nice explanation. Cheers +1.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `?ineq::Pen()` it seems to work like `plot()`; therefore, followings work for you.

```
Pen(x) 
Pen(y, add=T)
```

***Note:*** However, `add=T` cuts out part of your data since second plot has points which fall out of the limit of the first.

**Update on using `par(new=T)`:**

Using `par(new=T)` basically means overlaying two plots on top of each other; hence, it is important to make them with the same scale. We can achieve that by setting the same axis limits. That said, while using `add=T` argument it is desired to set limits of the axis to not loose any part of data. This is the best practice for overlaying two plots.

```
Pen(x, ylim=c(0,38), xlim=c(0,1))
par(new=T)
Pen(y, col="red", ylim=c(0,38), xlim=c(0,1), yaxt='n', xaxt='n')
```

Essentially, you can do the same with `add=T`.